# Store -> Configuration Unable to unserialize value backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

After i upgraded from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2 this issue shows when try to open Store -> configuration

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.
#0 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Serialized.php(55): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('a:1:{s:7:"optio...')
#1 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(601): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized->_afterLoad()
#2 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Serialized/ArraySerialized/Interceptor.php(323): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterLoad()
#3 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(441): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized\Interceptor->afterLoad()
#4 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(349): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->getFieldData(Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor), 'pdfinvoiceplus/...')
#5 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(325): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initElement(Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset), 'pdfinvoiceplus/...', '', '')
#6 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(265): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initFields(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset), Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group), Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section))
#7 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(211): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initGroup(Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group), Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form))
#8 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php(548): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initForm()
#9 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(666): Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_beforeToHtml()
#10 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#11 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system\\config\\f...')
#12 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system\\config\\f...')
#13 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('system\\config\\f...')
#14 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system\\config\\f...', true)
#15 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('system\\config\\f...', true)
#16 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/edit.phtml(22): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('form')
#17 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/gt52/...')
#18 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit), '/home/gt52/...', Array)
#19 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/gt52/...')
#20 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#23 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system.config.e...')
#24 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.e...')
#25 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.e...')
#26 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system.config.e...', true)
#27 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('system.config.e...')
#28 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#29 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#30 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#31 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#32 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#33 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col...')
#34 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#35 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#36 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col...', true)
#37 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('admin.scope.col...')
#38 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col')
#39 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#40 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#41 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col', true)
#42 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.col')
#43 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...')
#44 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#45 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#46 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', true)
#47 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.conta...')
#48 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content')
#49 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#50 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#51 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', true)
#52 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content')
#53 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#54 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#55 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#56 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#57 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#58 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page')
#59 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#60 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#61 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', true)
#62 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page')
#63 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#64 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#65 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#66 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#67 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#68 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#69 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#70 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#71 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#72 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#73 /home/gt52/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#74 /home/gt52/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#75 /home/gt52/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#76 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.2.0, Magento has started to use `json_encode` instead of `serialize` to save object values to the configuration table. You will manually have to retrieve serialized values from the `core_config_data` table with `` SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE 'pdfinvoiceplus/%'; ``.

Delete those records and re-do your configuration. (Or, if you prefer, unserialize the `value` column, json_encode it and save that to the table record.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please Do you have any tutorials/guide about the second option unserialize the value?